# Change specific route params without change the other params

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I use react and the route base on react-router-dom

```
<Route path=":groupId">

<Route path="users">
                      <Route index element={<UsersList />} />
                      <Route path=":userId" element={<EditUser />} />
                      <Route path="new" element={<NewUser />} />
                    </Route>
</Route>
```

I want to change the groupId that is the parent of the pages, but not change the other params

For example if I am in the new page I will change the parent groupId and still be in new page
I want to change groupId, but not child params/paths like users, or userId

The select group is in my page header and can be change in all the child's pages
[image]

Comment: so you want to change `groupId`, but not  child params/paths like `users`, or `userId`? pls, add more details to the question

Comment: exactly  change just the groupId but not child params

Comment: then you can use anything you know about changing route like `navigate` (`history.push` in old versions)

Comment: Where are you trying to change the `groupId` param value from? Can you [edit] your post to include a more complete [mcve]?